# How to change wordpress RSS to be in a specific format?

Tags: rss

I am working with an old system that takes in very specific format for RSS. The one thing that doesn't work is the featured image. I need the image to be in a

```
<image>
<url></url>
</image>
```

form but on Wordpress the image always shows in .

Any help here please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the action `rss2_item` (and `rss_item` for RSS 0.92) to output the required tags:

```php
function wpse_406826_rss_featured_image() {
    $src = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( null, 'medium' /* or whatever size you need */ );

    if ( $src ) {
        echo "<image><url>$src</url></image>";
    }
}

add_action( 'rss2_item', 'wpse_406826_rss_featured_image' );
add_action( 'rss_item',  'wpse_406826_rss_featured_image' );
```